# Is sphider (the search engine) much less vulnerable if I change the directory of the admin folder?

Tags: php, security, web, search-engine

I was just wondering if [sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) would become much less vulnerable if i would change the root directory of the admin folder and also change the name of the folder, these are the vulnerabilities i have found while searching on the net :

[cvedetails.com](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4330/Sphider.html)

Also if i did change the admin folder, would I have to change any links to other pages or do the other pages simply dont link to any files in the admin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a brief look at the thing, it looks like you should probably be able to do that.

It wouldn't become any less vulnerable, but it would become somewhat less discoverable. You would have some brief respite from automated attacks looking for known vulnerable scripts on predefined paths, but if the path leaked for any reason (and it's generally considered difficult and inadvisable to keep a path secret) then the page could be findable on search engines at which point you'd start getting hit again.

It would generally be a better idea to use the features of your web server (eg with `.htaccess` for Apache) to limit access to the `/admin` path, for example using HTTP Basic Authentication (`htpasswd`), limiting access by IP address, or HTTPS Client Certificates.

Personally from what I've just seen I wouldn't deploy this code anywhere; it is ancient and terrible and no-one seems to be looking after it even with the known serious vulns out there. Never mind the deeply misguided things the admin interface does, I don't even trust the public-facing search interface. (There are at minimum a bunch of XSS vulns in there.)